# Direct Authentication Issue In Console With ROAuth & Twitter

Tags: r, caching, oauth, twitter-oauth, httr

[image]
Hi,

I am trying to connect my twitter with R studio and ROauth. However when I try using direct authentication I experience the following issue

```
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Use a local file ('.httr-oauth'), to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
```

I type 1 into the console for YES. However when I try to run the line of code 
that searches for mentions of Samsung. The following happens

```
> source('/cloud/project/scripter.R')
[1] "Using direct authentication"
```

Then when 1 press one again. The console displays the following and does not pull mentions from twitter and display it in the console. Instead it prints the following.

```
[1] 1
```

Look forward to having some support as I am really enjoying everything about R so far.

You can see the attached image for more information

Regards,
Simeon